# can we use multiple extensions with custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

My first doubt is can we use multiple extensions with custom controller.
If yes, please check below code and let me know can I call "dosomething" method of Ext2?

Ext1:

```
public with sharing class Ext1 {
    public Ext1(){}
    public Ext1(Cont cn){}
          public pagereference dosomething(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/HelloWorld');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;
    }
}
```

Ext2:

```
public with sharing class Ext2 {
    public Ext2(){}
     public Ext2(Cont cn){}
      public pagereference dosomething(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/test1');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;
    }

}
```

Ext3:

```
public with sharing class Ext3 {
    public Ext3(){}
     public Ext3(Cont cn){}
      public pagereference dosomething(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/ContactForm');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;
    }
}
```

Cont.apxc

```
public with sharing class Cont {
    public Cont(){}
      public pagereference dosomething(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VFMain');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;
    }

}
```

Ext123.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="Cont" extensions="Ext1,Ext2">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!dosomething}" value="Click me"></apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6):

yes, you can have multiple extensions for one VF page. Reading [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) article, you can see rules regarding invoking methods with the same name from multiple extensions:

> Multiple controller extensions can be defined for a single page
>   through a comma-separated list. This allows for overrides of methods
>   with the same name
>
> Overrides are defined by whichever methods are defined in the
>   “leftmost” extension, or, the extension that is first in the
>   comma-separated list.

---

In your current case you have to rename method from `Ext2` to make it unique, or move `Ext2` to the first position in declaration among extensions.

```
<apex:page controller="Cont" extensions="Ext2, Ext1">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!dosomething}" value="Click me"></apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm):

> If multiple extensions defined for visualforce page it allows for
>   overrides of methods with the same name. Overrides are defined by
>   whichever methods are defined in the “leftmost” extension, or, the
>   extension that is first in the comma-separated list.

The first class in your extensions will have always the highest priority. Thus, `dosomething` method of `Ext1` will be always get called.

If you want to execute `dosomething` method of `Ext2` then you have to change the order of extensions specified in `apex:page` as

```
<apex:page controller="Cont" extensions="Ext2,Ext1">
```

or rename the method of either extension.

Comment: I have an action function in the extension controller class which I moved from the custom controller. How can I call that? I was calling it from custom_controller using => apex:actionFunction name="updateRec" action="{!updateData}" 
Now updateData is moved to extension class.
When I load vf page I am getting Unknown method 'custom_controller.updateData()'
How to solve this